# Is this website encrypted or not?

Tags: tls, http

This site: http://www.wootbox.de/

I would say no, because according to FF and Chrome it uses http
According to ssllabs.com and the support of the website it uses https: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wootbox.de

I also tried https://www.wootbox.de and https://wootbox.de but I get always http://www.wootbox.de

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL https://www.wootbox.de/ exists for the sole purpose of redirecting you to the unencrypted http:// version using an HTTP "302" Redirect.  The 302 response below tells the web browser to resubmit their request to the "Location:" of http://www.wootbox.de/.

```
$ wget -S -O - https://www.wootbox.de
--2016-08-11 18:40:16--  https://www.wootbox.de/
Resolving www.wootbox.de (www.wootbox.de)... 104.45.3.115
Connecting to www.wootbox.de (www.wootbox.de)|104.45.3.115|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.0 302 Moved
  Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2016 18:37:55 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Location: http://www.wootbox.de/
  Content-Length: 0
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

This would not normally be a problem - many sites prefer you use HTTP for non-sensitive actions to save on the overhead.  However, I notice that the login page is set to POST your credentials to the unencrypted HTTP address:

```
<form action="http://www.wootbox.de/anmeldung" method="post" id="login_form" class="box wootbox-auth">
  ...
  <div class="form-group form-error">
  <label for="passwd">Passwort</label>
  <input class="is_required validate account_input form-control" type="password" data-validate="isPasswd" id="passwd" name="passwd" value="">
  ...
```

This implies that the site is actively eschewing security, not merely redirecting browsers when security isn't necessary.

Tools like SSL Labs don't care about that HTTP redirect, so they probe the working SSL server for all their testing and provide you a report.  However, the application layer - the thing the SSL connects you to - tells your browser to come back without SSL, and so it does.

Comment: I can't understand people who go through the trouble to set up a proper TLS certificate and then only use it to redirect to a http site. Outright shameful in an age were https should be the default and http the exception.

Comment: @Philipp, many of them do it merely to capture the users who are looking for their site and have come to expect that a site is on https as much or more than on http.  The alternative is to look "down" to users who went looking for the secure site.  I agree, it's ironic.

Answer (score 1):

No, the site is not encrypted. It is capable of establishing an encrypted connection, and hence ssllabs reports that it supports encryption, but as soon as you do it simply redirects you back to the non-encrypted version of the site.